# Shared Home Structure group has the wrong PublishPath which means items are deployed to the wrong place

Tags: cme, 2011-sp1

I am a little baffled by this issue in a SDL Tridion 2011 SP1-2 environment.

Pages from one publication are suddenly going to the wrong folder - `/at/german/german` instead of `/at/german`

Looking at the Item XML for the Home Structure group (opening the Shared item rather than editting the parent) reveals that the Publish Path is wrong there. However it is set correctly on the publication. **The Structure group is not localised and should be taking the directory from 00 Empty Parent**

Other publications with a similar set up e.g. `/be/french` are fine and publish to the correct location.

Here is the relevant Item XML

from the at-de Home Structure group (shared)

[image]

from the be-fr Home Structure group (shared)

[image]

from the at-de Publication

[image]

from the be-fr Publication

[image]

I've tried localising and unlocalising the structure group but this had no effect. I can't see any hotfixes which mention this issue for HR2. Unfortunately I can't check whether this issue exists in other environments as the publication has only been created in Stage.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried rebuilding your path mappings?

For SQL Server, you can do this in the following way:

`EXEC eda_org_items_rebuildpaths NULL, 3`

The last parameter is the Publication ID and this will rebuild and correct all the entries in path_mappings table. Please make sure you replace the Publication ID according to your setup.

Comment: That looks like the one, thanks Ryan. I'll get it run and accept if it works!

Comment: Worked a treat.

Comment: We got exact issue with 2013 sp1 and applied this solution. Working fine for 2013sp1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably stating the obvious here, but have you made sure that the '*Directory*' field on the Root structure group isn't set to *german*?

Given that the publication has been set right (guessing *\at\german*) then having *german* set for the *Directory* field on the structure group would result in what you're seeing.

Comment: Agreed, that's what I thought but the structure group isn't localised so it's the same as the 00 Empty parent - `/`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure below list of points are configured correctly:

- On "00 Empty Parent" publication, configure

  - Publication Path as "\"
  - Publication Url as "/"
- On **Root** Structure Group of "00 Empty Parent" publication

  - Leave Directory field as Empty
- On "Austria-German" Publication, configure

  - Publication Path as "\at\german"
  - Publication Url as "/at/german"

Now should see the values on the XML as follows

00 Empty Parent Publication:

```
<tcm:PublishPath>\</tcm:PublishPath>
<tcm:PublishLocationPath>\</tcm:PublishLocationPath>
<tcm:PublishLocationUrl>/</tcm:PublishLocationUrl>
```

AT-DE Publication:

```
<tcm:PublishPath>\at\german</tcm:PublishPath>
<tcm:PublishLocationPath>\at\german</tcm:PublishLocationPath>
<tcm:PublishLocationUrl>/at/german/</tcm:PublishLocationUrl>
```